Facing problem to configure openai api for ocr app development
I am very much new to OCR development. I want to build a app using python tesseract for ocr then parse the fields using openai here is the code so far i have tried
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import openai
from pdf2image import convert_from_path


pdf_path='path of my pdfpath'
pages= convert_from_path(pdf_path)

for i, page in enumerate(pages):
     #Run ocr each page
     text=pytesseract.image_to_string(page)
     print(f"Text on page {i + 1}:\n{text}\n")


openai.api_key=os.getenv("my API key")

response=openai.ChatCompletion.create(model="gpt-4-turbo",
  messages=[
    {"role": "system", "content": "Parse the following text into structured JSON fields for a bank statement."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "Please parse Customer ID, Currency, Account Number, Account Type,Account Title,Tran Date,Transaction ref,Debit,Credit,Balance"}
  ])

Now i am getting error
APIRemovedInV1:
You tried to access openai.ChatCompletion, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0 - see the README at https://github.com/openai/openai-python for the API.

You can run `openai migrate` to automatically upgrade your codebase to use the 1.0.0 interface. 

Alternatively, you can pin your installation to the old version, e.g. `pip install openai==0.28`

A detailed migration guide is available here: https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742

so it is saying API remove. is there any way to configure open ai for ocr development

This question is similar to: OpenAI API error: "You tried to access openai.ChatCompletion, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
